# Ububut 18.0.4 LTS:- unable to start TCP/UDP discard service on port 9 and time service on port 37

Tags: ubuntu, socket, time

I have ubuntu client 18.0.4, I am unable to telnet localhost on port 9 and port 37.

```
root@ubuntu:~# telnet 127.0.0.1 37
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@ubuntu:~# telnet 127.0.0.1 9
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/xinetd.d/time
i# default: off
# description: An RFC 868 time server. This protocol provides a
# site-independent, machine readable date and time. The Time service sends back
# to the originating source the time in seconds since midnight on January first
# 1900.
# This is the tcp version.
service time
{
    disable     = no <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,I have changed to no
    type        = INTERNAL
    id      = time-stream
    socket_type = stream
    protocol    = tcp
    user        = root
    wait        = no
}

# This is the udp version.
service time
{
    disable     = no
    type        = INTERNAL
    id      = time-dgram
    socket_type = dgram
    protocol    = udp
    user        = root
    wait        = yes
}
root@ubuntu:~#
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/xinetd.d/discard
i# default: off
# description: An RFC 863 discard server.
# This is the tcp version.
service discard
{
    disable     = no
    type        = INTERNAL
    id      = discard-stream
    socket_type = stream
    protocol    = tcp
    user        = root
    wait        = no
}

# This is the udp version.
service discard
{
    disable     = no
    type        = INTERNAL
    id      = discard-dgram
    socket_type = dgram
    protocol    = udp
    user        = root
    wait        = yes
}
root@ubuntu:~#
```

I have restarted xinetd couple of times but no luck. Moreover I also have services configured on /etc/services.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/services | grep 37
time        37/tcp      timserver
time        37/udp      timserver

root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/services | grep 9
discard     9/tcp       sink null
discard     9/udp       sink null
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Please check the formatting of your post - it's rough on the eyes trying to read it.

Comment: The first character in both xinetd config files is an `i`. If that's not a typo in the question, it's definitely a syntax error. In any case, have you checked the xinetd log?

Comment: Like berndbausch I suspect your xinetd is not actually running. Please show ```systemctl status xinetd``` and ```ps awux | grep xinetd``` and ```lsof -p $(pidof xinetd)```